# What does "&" mean in CSS and why i'm receiving errors?

Tags: jquery, css

CSS

```
button{
  margin-top: 4em;
  background-color: #ff3a3a;
  outline: none;
  .active &{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0 0;
  }
}
```

I found a template website on codepen.io, but when i put exactly this code on my IDE - I'm having error at ".active &{". I also included these libraries, did i miss something?

```
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/78060/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
```

Comment: That's less/sass/scss or some sort of CSS preprocessor, not plain CSS. Compiles to `button {
  margin-top: 4em;
  background-color: #ff3a3a;
  outline: none;
}
.active button {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0 0;
}`

Comment: can i change something in scss or preprocessor rather than re-writing plenty of code?

Comment: Hi! Yes, you can edit the SCSS file, but you still need to run the SCSS through its compiler to create normal CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Sass or scss is server rendered, not in browser.**
>   So, for in your project can make it scss file (by changing extension) & then convert it to css by cmd prompt

- Install sass by `npm install -g sass` by command prompt (make sure you've npm installed already, otherwise install npm first)
- convert the extention of your css file to scss, like -

> **1.scss**

```
button{
  margin-top: 4em;
  background-color: #ff3a3a;
  outline: none;
  .active &{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0 0;
  }
}
```

- Now run this command in command prompt `sass 1.scss 1.css`
  (make sure the path of where you opened or running your cmd prompt terminal)
- Look that you have now a css file produced in same location. link 1.css file & will work

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know about & is that it is usually with 
`<span>&times;</span`
Which creates an 'X'